# This is the output I get when running my dart code in flutter project in Android Studio

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

As I run my code on Android studio, and I want to see my code output in an emulator but while running an emulator it shows error system UI is not responding.

[image]

Comment: When adding text artifacts to your questions, please try to keep them as text - a formatting tool is available. This makes them easier to read, and allows clipboards, search engine crawlers and screen readers to operate normally. These things won't work when text is rendered in image.

Answer (score 0):

this error is provided because you have not accepted all the android SDK agrement, try to run this on terminal `flutter doctor --android-licenses`